# Как показывать элементы при активности пользователи и скрывать при её отсутстсвии?

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

Нужно, чтобы элементы скрывались, когда пользователь не двигает мышкой 5 секунд, и чтобы они показывались обратно, как только мышь дёрнется (и так по кругу).

Может есть готовые плагины или решения для этой задачи?

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить всем элементам, которые нужно скрыть, класс `autohide` и добавить на страницу вот такой код:

```
var timeout = null;

$(document).on('mousemove', function() {
    if (timeout !== null) {
        $(".autohide").show();
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }

    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.autohide').hide();
        timeout = null;
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: т.е. при каждом движении указателя мыши производится проверка на наличие таймера? не слишком ли это ресурсо-затратно?

Comment: попробовал, не работает

Comment: @SdafsFasafs Очень странно. Вот рабочий пример https://jsfiddle.net/xue0mg6m/

Comment: @СебастьянПерейро , действительно странно, на моем сайте что то не работает(

Comment: @SdafsFasafs, проверьте консоль. Если этот код не работает, то в консоли должны быть какие-нибудь ошибки.

Comment: @MatveySafronov, проверил и не заметил сколь-нибудь значительного  увеличения потребления ресурсов.

Answer (score 0):

Готовых плагинов я не знаю, но вероятно Вам следует отталкиваться от [этого](https://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) и от setTimeout

Comment: Меня опередили с ответом, - Себастьян Перейро прислал вам небольшую заготовку